# How to set context path to the hyperlink url in java

Tags: jsp, hyperlink, struts

```
 <html:link href="/dnweb/displayFindDeviceId.do" styleClass="small" onclick="appendHref(this)"> 
       <bean:message key="link.find"/>
 </html:link>
```

The above code having context name as "/dnweb". This is given as hardcoded.   But i need it as dynamically.

If you changed the context name to your project. Automatically it has to be changed. How can i do for this.

i have the code as

```
<html:link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/displayFindDeviceId.do"
```

But this is giving an error.

Comment: check this link ...[click][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065843/changing-tomcat-web-application-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set the context path using html taglib tag i can set the context path using a variable by using scriptliet tags like

i took variable urlName to collect contextPath here.

```
<jsp:useBean id="urlName" class="java.lang.String" scope="page" />
 <% urlName= request.getContextPath() + "/displayFindDeviceId.do"; %>
 <html:link href="<%=urlName %>" styleClass="small" onclick="appendHref(this)"> 
      <bean:message key="link.find"/>  
 </html:link>
```

As per this code it is working fine in my localhost.

Thanks to Bozho and JB.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `pageContext`. Simply use `${request.contextPath}`

Note that for older versions of JSP you may need to set:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

But try to upgrade your servlet container to support a newer version.

Comment: you still haven't answered my question "what error is it giving"

Comment: It is giving as error to link 'http://localhost:8080/dnweb/device/$%7Brequest.contextPath%7D/displayFindDeviceId.do But it should be like this below path 'http://localhost:8080/dnweb/displayFindDeviceId.do'.

Comment: what's the JSP version? What's on the top of your JSP (jsp directives)?

Comment: JSP version: **1.2** '<%@ page language="java" %> <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %> <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %> <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-ext.tld" prefix="ext" %> <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %> <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/utility.tld" prefix="util" %> <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/c.tld" prefix="c" %>' these are only i have used to my page.

Comment: we can't upgrade the server. We are in project.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/dnweb/device/$%7Brequest.contextPath%7D/displayFindDeviceId.do` it is showing the link as above. But it should be like `http://localhost:8080/dnweb/displayFindDeviceId.do`.

Comment: You are doing something very wrong above - you should not have the standard tlds in WEB-INF/tld. And your whole EL is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Struts1 tag, isn't it? If so, then you should use the `action` or the `page` attribute to be able to use context-relative (or even module-related) URLs. See http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html:link for details.

Answer (score 0):

**${pageContext.request.contextPath}** worked for me (spring version 4.3.5.RELEASE and jstl version 1.2). The setting isELIgnored="false" is still needed.